# How to get position of scrollbar automatically when a scrollbar is at position at nearly half way by the user so that it can call other function?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a function which can we activated automatically when user is at a particular position on scrollbar.It is like I want to create a result page which automatically loads more result when the user is at just a little far from end but I don't know how to get it automatically.I can get position of scollbar by using scrollbar.get method but how to check when scollbar is moved by user?

Comment: do you want the same effect if the user uses the arrow keys to scroll, or only when they use the scrollbar?

Comment: I want the effect only when they uses scollbar .I am very gretefull to you .Your many answers has helped me a lot sir.Please can you provide me some example of how to do it

Comment: FWIW, it would be slightly easier to do it no matter how the widget is scrolled. Otherwise you'll have to handle both the scrollbar and scroll wheel, and the user might find it odd if you autoload with the scrollbar and not with the page down key. Though, if you don't care about the mouse wheel or page down keys, it's easy either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this special behavior only when they use the scrollbar and not when they use page up, page down, or the mouse wheel, you can have the scrollbar call a proxy rather than the text widget's `yview` method.

The proxy would need to call the `yview` command as normal, and then it can do the autoload function.

For example, you can get the index of the last visible line an then compare it to a target line, such as the fifth-to-last line. If the last visible line is past the target, load another page.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

COUNT = 0

def handle_scroll(*args):
    # call the yview command to update the text widget based
    # on the scrollbar position
    text.yview(*args)

    # load another page if the user scrolls to within 5 lines
    # of the end
    maxy = text.winfo_height()
    last_visible_line = text.index("@0,{} linestart".format(maxy))
    target = text.index("end-5 lines")
    if text.compare(last_visible_line, ">", target):
        load_page()

def load_page():
    """Simulate adding a page of results"""
    global COUNT
    for i in range(30):
        COUNT += 1
        text.insert("end", "Result #{}\n".format(COUNT))

root = tk.Tk()
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=handle_scroll)
text = tk.Text(root,height=20, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

# simulate loading the initial page
load_page()

tk.mainloop()
```

Note: if you want this auto-load feature no matter how the user scrolls the widget (scrollbar, mouse wheel, keyboard), use the proxy in place of `vsb.set` rather than in place of `text.yview`. In that way the function will be called every time the contents of the widget changes or is scrolled.

Comment: thank you sir,but I have one last question , my data is in scrollbel canvas in which a frame window is there with multiple canvases in which each canvas has some different labels.So will it work with them too

Comment: One last thing is that what canges should be done in 'last_visible_line' and 'target' in case of scollebel canvas because I thing the index there must work differently also look at this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028973/why-my-scollbar-and-canvas-doesnt-synchronise

Comment: @RahulSoni: I'm sorry, I misspoke earlier. I was assuming you were using a text widget. For the canvas the concept is roughly the same (ie: using the `handle_scroll` proxy) but you'll have to look at the values passed to `handle_scroll` to determine what part of the canvas is visible.

Comment: It wasn't your fault at all, it was mine as I forgot to mention this important details in this question.Now the only problem left is this:-     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028973/why-my-scollbar-and-canvas-doesnt-synchronise