# Why my scrollbar and canvas doesn't synchronise?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created a scrollable canvas. In which a frame window is there and there are many canvases in it which shows data in form of various labels?
Actually I have created everything like frame configuration to update canvas scollregion but I sometimes randomly gets a bug that is when I destroy a canvas in a frame then sometimes the size of scrollbar adjust automatically but sometimes it doesn't change and scollbar shows a region with no data a large blank space at the bottom is generated sometimes and also when I cleared the frame window completely by destroying all of its children widgets then even I checked on console by print statements that everything is cleared but still the results on gui tkinter windows are still there till I switch the page and it is also occuring randomly why? Sometimes everything goes as planned but sometimes not can you figure why?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have provided now the minimal reproductive example.Open this and switch frame by click on 'Detail Box2' now click on 'clear all' then switch frame again then click on 'clear all'.I have now mentioned complete details. check it out.Thanks also in this I wanted to implement auto scrollbar because I took 500 results and my whole pc hanged and gui crashed please help me

Comment: I don't understand this: _"When you click on 'Details Box2' ...  but now when you switch to 'Detail Box 2"_ How can I switch to "Details Box2" when I'm already on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be many problems, but it seems that the most significant is that you are creating two canvases but only saving a reference to the last one that was created.

At startup `self.canvas` will point to the first canvas. When you click on "Detail Box2", `self.canvas` is reset to be a new canvas. You no longer have a reference to the first canvas. From that point on, any time you do anything with `self.canvas`, it's only doing it to the second canvas.

Until you fix that, I don't think it's possible for anything else to work correctly.

Comment: I have spllit that class into two classes thank you . i am still so naive,I can't figure it out by myself thank you so much